# Deallocated instance exception with threads

Tags: objective-c

I've a problem with an app for Mac that I'm writing in Objective-c.
I've this situation:

1. In main thread (GUI):

> ```
> ftEngine = [[FileT alloc] init];
> [ftEngine setParameters:searchWord selectedEngine:[[pbEngines selectedItem] title] actualPage:0];
> NSThread* thFileT = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:ftEngine selector:@selector(setTotalResult) object:nil]; [thFileT start];
> ```

1. In child (ftEngine previous declared):

> ```
> -(void)setTotalResult {
>     NSError* nsError = nil;
>     NSURL* urlCompleteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:m_completeSearchWord];
> }
> ```

m_completeSearchWord is initialized by setParameters function previously utilized.

And now.. my problem is:
When thread is started, it call setTotalResult function and i'll get an exception when I try to use m_completeSearchWord.

It's strange becacuse if I don't use a thread, all works correctly!

Exception is:

```
2011-09-08 23:24:06.731 GUI[12935:1a07] *** -[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1003cc650
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may not have retained `m_completeSearchWord` correctly when you initialized it.  Add the body of `-setParameters` if you want help confirming that.

Comment: I've declared it as a property:
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* m_strSearchWord;

Comment: Did you set the property with a property setter, or did you set the ivar directly?

Answer (score 0):

When calling selectors in a new thread, make sure that the selector has been properly wrapped with an autorelease pool :

```
-(void) setTotalResult {
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    ...
    [pool release];
}
```

I see all manner of memory related issues when I forget to add the pool and your error definitely rings a bell.